# Page Scroll Problems with CardView and ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-cardview, android-scrollview

I have a XML layout as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/accounts_details_page_background_color">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/overview_cardview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
    card_view:ignore="PrivateResource">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_compliance_details_overview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@string/compliance_details_fragment_overview"
            android:textColor="@color/compliance_overview_title_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/policy_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/fragment_compliance_details_overview" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/last_check_time_only"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/policy_name" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/horizontal_line_compliance"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/last_check_time_only" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/compliance_policy_status_explanation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/horizontal_line_compliance" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/last_check_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:text="@string/last_compliance_check_time"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/compliance_policy_status_explanation" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/compliance_user_action_advice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:text="@string/compliance_user_advice"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/last_check_time" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/details_cardview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/overview_cardview"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    card_view:cardElevation="2dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/policy_details_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@string/policy_details_title"
            android:textColor="@color/compliance_overview_title_color"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/compliance_rules_listview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

When the ListView has more than 3-4 rows the page does not scroll. The ListView does not scroll either.

I tried wrapping the whole thing in a NestedScrollView but that just gets the ListView scrolling and not even entirely.

I want the entire page to scroll and end scrolling when the ListView ends. Any ideas would help.

Comment: what is your ListView Layout Param?

Comment: @shb its match_parent for width, wrap_content for height

Comment: your list view is expanding when you are adding items as because the height is wrap content, therefore it's not scrolling, try "match parent" for the height.

Comment: match_parent did not work either. Even tried layout weight since the parent is a linear layout, no good.

Comment: when you use match parent does it still act like the same "3-4 rows"?

Comment: Yup, I have a few rows showing and the others are cut off.

Comment: Only the view hierarchy on the question isn't helping much to solve the issue.

Comment: added the complete layout, if that helps

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need constraint layout for what you are doing.
2. Read about view weights.
3. Try this. (replace androix.* for your components)

```html
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/overview_cardview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:contentPadding="4dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="2dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fragment_compliance_details_overview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="test"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/policy_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="test"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/fragment_compliance_details_overview" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/last_check_time_only"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="test"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/policy_name" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/horizontal_line_compliance"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/compliance_policy_status_explanation"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="test"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/horizontal_line_compliance" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/last_check_time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:text="test"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/compliance_policy_status_explanation" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/compliance_user_action_advice"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:text="@string/has_accepted_your_invitation_to_fynd"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/last_check_time" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/details_cardview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:contentPadding="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/overview_cardview"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        card_view:cardElevation="2dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/policy_details_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="test"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/compliance_rules_listview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```